# http_ssl_module failed to install when compile from source code of nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, certbot

I am trying to setup my https using certbot , so I need to recompile ngx adding '--with-http_ssl_module', here is the complete steps：

```
 - sudo make clean 
 - sudo  ./auto/configure --prefix=/var/www/html --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --with-pcre --with-http_ssl_module  --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/etc/nginx/modules
 - check Makefile , I can see 'http_ssl_module' added in objs/Makefile  
 - sudo make 
 - sudo make install
```

After completed all steps above(no error observed)
I checked 'ngx_modules.o'*(still missing ssl module)* and ran command below

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d feedme.pub 
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log 
The nginx plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration. 
The error was: PluginError('Nginx build is missing SSL module (--with-http_ssl_module).')
```

Also , I checked my ssl lib- libssl is intalled:

```
ldconfig -p | grep libssl
    libssl3.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl3.so
    libssl.so.1.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
    libssl.so.1.0.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
    libssl.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
```

Anyone can help to answer why I am not able to build '--with-http_ssl_module' in ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :

1. in ./configration stepps added
   `--with-openssl=/usr/include/openssl'` options , since '--with-http_ssl_module' need to use openssl
2. when build I got another error :

> ```
> make -f objs/Makefile
> make[1]: Entering directory `/root/soft/nginx-1.17.3'
> cd /usr/local/openssl \
> && if [ -f Makefile ]; then make clean; fi \
> && ./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl/.openssl no-shared no-threads  \
> && make \
> && make install_sw LIBDIR=lib
> /bin/sh: line 2: ./config: No such file or directory
> make[1]: *** [/usr/local/openssl/.openssl/include/openssl/ssl.h] Error 127  make[1]: Leaving directory `
> ```

What I did was to manually modify

```
./auto/lib/openssl/conf
```

change the path below to the actual location on my ubuntu

```
    CORE_INCS="$CORE_INCS <your openssl lib's path>/include"
    CORE_DEPS="$CORE_DEPS <your openssl lib's path>/include/openssl/ssl.h"
    CORE_LIBS="$CORE_LIBS <your local libssl.a path>/lib/libssl.a"
    CORE_LIBS="$CORE_LIBS <your local libcrypto.a path>/lib/libcrypto.a"
```

Then run make , everything works out